# C++ : Recursion with a vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I will like some help, the code used to work, now it doesn't. Help.
The purpose is for the user to see the vector backwards using a recursion.

```
int listar(int v[5], int l); 

void main(){ 
    int vector[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
    listar(vector,-1); 
} 

int listar(int v[5],int l){ 
    int n=0; 
    if (n<=5){ 
        cout<< listar(v, n+1)<< endl; 
    return v[n]; 
    } 
return v[5];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment "...the code used to work, now it doesn't"? It is difficult to help without knowing about your problem.

Comment: The posted code does not even compile.

Comment: Did you mean to make an array of 5 vectors or were you looking to have one vector with 5 items in it?

Comment: why don't you use l instead of n

Comment: Let me guess...  Does it just give a stack overflow and print nothing?

Answer (score 0):

In the method `int listar(int v[5],int l){` you are not using the parameter `l` at all. Shouldn't the code be using that instead of making `n=0` in each recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The code is recursive,
You have listar being called by listar.

Recursion is fine, but as you always set n to 0, and then say "if n<5", then you'll get infinite recursion.

I think this is what you mean:

```
int vector[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
    listar(vector,0); 
} 

int listar(int v[5],int l){  
    if (l<=5){ 
        cout<< listar(v, l+1)<< endl;
    }
    return v[l];
```

But this is quite different

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
int listar(int v[],int index);

int main(){ 
    int vector[5]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
    listar(vector,(sizeof(vector)/sizeof(*vector))-1); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 

int listar(int v[],int index)
{
    if(index<0) return -1;
    cout<<v[index]<<"\n";
    listar(v,index-1);
    return v[index];
}
```

Note: You [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) always use int main as the signature of main function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int listar(vector<int> v, int l); 

int main(){ 
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    listar(v,-1); 
    return 0;
} 

int listar(vector<int> v,int n){ 
    if (n<5){ 
        cout<< listar(v, n+1)<< endl; 
    return v[n]; 
    } 
return v[5]; 
}
```